# Делать UPDATE, если дата пустая

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, select, update

Имеется такая таблица:

[image: Таблица]
У меня есть два input type="text", на них я повесил дэйтпикер, на кнопке "Сохранить" весит обычный UPDATE полей в базе. Все работает отлично, но, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы если человек выбрал дату и она входит в диапазон из этих дат, говорить пользователю "Дата уже занята" У меня все абсолютно работает, все сохранение идет у меня аяксом, вопрос в том что я не понимаю, как сделать проверку если диапазон дат уже занят.
Подытожим, человек выбирает обе даты, жмет кнопку Сохранить, и, если выбранная дата попадает в диапазон из этих дат, которые имеются в бд, говорить пользователю что дата занята.

P.S. вот сам UPDATE

```
public static function SaveDisplayTime($datefrom, $dateto, $id){
$sql = "UPDATE settings_comments SET `comments_from` = '".$datefrom."', `comments_to` = '".$dateto."' WHERE `id` = '".$id."';";
    Model::query($sql);
}
```

Надеюсь что понятно объяснил, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если я добавлю дату С 2018-05-14 11:43:43 ПО 2018-05-14 11:53:02, то соотвественно UPDATE не должен происходить.

Comment: Нужно сделать селект в коде перед обновлением на поиск записей в данном диапазоне, и если запись есть, то вернуть ошибку на клиента

Comment: @VyacheslavGusser Пытался как-то так                               
   SELECT * FROM settings_comments
   WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() > comments_from && 
   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() < comments_to;";

Comment: Я думаю что надо искать записи у которых даты в периоде который передал клиент, а CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @VyacheslavGusser прощу прощения, не тот запрос скинул) у меня просто есть еще один селект похожий

Comment: Скидывайте нужный, посмотрим :)

Comment: *как сделать проверку если диапазон дат уже занят* Проверить ОТДЕЛЬНЫМ запросом. `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM settings_comments WHERE @start <= comments_to AND @end >= comments_from` и сравнить результат с нулём. Если НЕ ноль - имеется пересечение, и надо вывести алерт, иначе сформировать и выполнить запрос на пополнение/обновление. PS. Если у Вас там ДАТЫ - почему в полях имеется и компонента времени?

Comment: Видимо потому что это не даты, а timestamp

Comment: @Akina по мимо дат еще соответственно и время проверять

Comment: Если проверять - то сразу уж дату-время...